# Is there a better way to redirect all open sessions on a website?

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a website using flask that displays some data. Occasionally, the data that is being displayed needs to be refreshed so I need the website to reload to display the 503 page, and then once it's done to reload again to display the refreshed data. Here's how I accomplish this as of right now:

(Relevant server sided python:)

```py
@app.route("/checkifreloading/")
def checkifreloading():
    with open('static/dat.json') as data:
        try:
            loads(data.read())  # When not refreshing, data will be a valid JSON string
            return encode({"code": 200, "response": False})
        except JSONDecodeError:  # When refreshing, data will be blank
            return encode({"code": 200, "response": True})
```

(Relevant client sided HTML:)

```html
<body onload="load_func()">
    <!-- data display -->
</body>
```

(Relevant client sided JS:)

```
async function getAsync(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.json();
}

function check_for_refresh() {
    getAsync("../checkifreloading/").then(function(results) {
        if (results['response'] === true) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}

function load_func() {
    setInterval(check_for_refresh, 5000); // check every five seconds
}
```

tldr: i send a GET to an endpoint that returns true if the data is refreshing every five seconds

This has problems, especially once you have a lot of open sessions. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

On a not too large scale application you can use Ajax,
Apparently if you're building a bigger orojects use Async or Service worker,But in this case service workers work best.

Answer (score -1):

The best ways to get and disply data with javascript are
1.Ajax
2. Async requests
3. Sevice Workers
Do well to read about them

Comment: Hi DevFeranmi, this is good advice in general, but it doesn't really answer the question... can you point out which of these would be better for this particular case and why?